# Using matplotlib to draw a circle filled with squares

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

I have to do this assignment - this is my first time using Python and we didn't learn it in lectures.

Our requirements are to use matplotlib in Python 2.7 and to write a program that accepts a radius as input and draws a circle of that radius. We then need to draw 1x1 squares over that circle, but only those squares that are inside of the circle or on the border. Ordinal numbers need to be printed over those squares.

This is the code I've written:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r = input()
ax = plt.gca() 
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0),radius=r,
                       facecolor=(.7,.7,.7),edgecolor='black')) 
plt.xlim([-r-2,r+2]) 
plt.ylim([-r-2,r+2]) 
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.savefig('new.pdf') 
plt.show()
```

I don't understand how to add so many squares and text to this circle. I can add only one by one, for example, `(0,0),(1,1)`. Please help, and sorry for any mistakes.

For `r=10`, it should look like this:

[image: r=10]

Comment: well, you can draw these squares in (two) for loop(s)

Comment: ussing loops:
    ... 
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0),radius=r,
                       facecolor=(.7,.7,.7),edgecolor='black')) 
    for x in range(-r,r):
        for y in range(-r,r):
            if x*x + y*y < r*r:
                ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x,y),1,1,
                                facecolor=(.7,.5,.5,.5),edgecolor=(.2,.1,.1,.5))) 

    plt.xlim([-r-2,r+2]) 
    ....
but the squares don't cover the whole circle (bottom and left side)

Comment: code written in one line is quite unreadable (and I don't have matplotlib installed), but here is a hint - loop in x only from 0 to r and plot two squares - for positive and negative value (you'll always have to shift the negative one)

Comment: as for numbering the squares - apart of plotting them, you can save them all to the list and then sort them first by y and x val - that way you'll be able to write text to them easily